# Activate a conda environment when Debugging a python C++ module Visual Studio and VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-code, conda

I am building a C++ module for python using dependencies in a conda virtual environment. The problem is I can't figure out how to activate my conda environment before launching the C++ debugger in Visual Studio or in VSCode.Is there a way to have the debugger window activate a conda environment? Everything works find if I open a shell activate the conda environment and then launch Visual Studio or VSCode from the active shell.

In other words I want a way to tell the debugger window to run a command before starting the debug process.

```
conda activate $myenv
```

Comment: you can add a prelaunch task to the launch config

Comment: Does that task happen in the same shell as the launch? I was under the impression that it does not. Is there an equivalent for Visual Studio proper?